# Eclipse content assist: accepting the selection with the . or ( keys

Tags: eclipse, pydev

When using Visual Studio, I can accept an Intellisense selection by hitting either the . or the ( keys, as well as the enter key. I would like to configure Eclipse to do the same with its Content Assist feature, but I can't see any way to do so.

Is this possible? In case it matters, I am specifically referring to Eclipse Helios with Pydev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that it's under Preferences->Pydev->Editor->Code Completion. There are checkboxes for 'Apply completeion on .' and 'Apply completion on ('. I guess it's a Pydev-specific thing, and not an Eclipse feature.

Comment: The JDT Java editor does not contain this feature, so it is Pydev-specific.

Answer (score 1):

you can customize the hot key for content assist via preferences - general - keys

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that's not quite what I'm looking for. That only lets me customize the key used to show the content assist window. I'm looking to customize the keys used to accept the selection in an already open content assist window.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to customize the key to accept the selection. See preferences - java - editor - content assist